# How to plot several counters in a same graph?

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization

I have a dataframe with classes, size of the set and a vocabulary counter:

```
>>> df[["Q",'S04Q02']].groupby('S04Q02')['Q'].sum()
Class
Other:                  {'Size': 1, 'employed': 1, 'in': 16, 'the': ...
PSOE:                   {'Size': 24, 'unemployed': 25, '': 4217, 'be...
UNDI:                   {'Size': 27, 'self': 7, 'employed': 25, '': ...
PP:                     {'Size': 6, 'self': 1, 'employed': 8, '': 89...
Ciudadanos:             {'Size': 34, 'unemployed': 35, '': 4975, 'pe...
Podemos:                {'Size': 5, 'employed': 11, 'in': 126, 'the'...
```

I would like to represent it. What would the the best way?

I tried to do a loop and bar chart. Which is not optimal as it doesn't help me to compare:

```
for row in counters.iterrows():
    plt.bar(row.keys(), row.values())
```

But got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-fdd41c7f0ffa> in <module>
----> 1 for row in counters.iterrows():
      2     plt.bar(row.keys(), row.values())

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

Comment: One way to compare frequency lists of words is with a [word cloud](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html). In your case that would be one word cloud per political party. The word clould typically skips common words (`stopwordsset`). [Here](https://github.com/Alir3z4/stop-words/blob/master/spanish.txt) is a possible list for Spanish stopwords.

Comment: @JohanC Many thanks! The words are in English here, so it should be easier